# What species are these juvenile birds?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

What species are these juvenile birds found at São José dos Campos, Brazil?

[image]

Comment: A puppy is a young dog. There exist a number of correct terms for birds (chick, hatchling , nestling, fledgling and other species specific terms). See [here](https://www.backyardchirper.com/blog/what-do-you-call-baby-birds/) for more information

Comment: @Remi.b Excuse me. I'm Brazilian and I wrote wrong.

Comment: @LCarvalho No worries. I make plenty of english mistakes myself. Can you please add the location where you took that picture?

Comment: From São José dos Campos

Comment: I am flattered by my question having had so much attention from reputed people. Well, I found the right site to ask. I did not expect it to be like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The birds in question appear to be fledgling [eared doves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eared_dove?wprov=sfla1), which belong to the species *Zenaida auriculata*. The beak color, eye markings, and overall feather coloration were most indicative when IDing.

Here's a few images of what the doves may look like once matured:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The OP is from Brazil, so assuming he saw them in Brazil, could it be [*Zenaida auriculata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eared_dove)?

Comment: @Remi.b Yes, after doing a bit of reading, I agree. I've updated my response to *Z. auriculata* instead of *Z. macroura*. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds right esp. now that we know the location. +1